# Number of pairs $(x, y)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $ x $ and $ y $ are natural numbers such that $4×3^x-1=5^y$, determine the number of 
>   solutions $(x, y) $ of the equation $ 4×3^x-1=5^y.$

I tried taking logarithms, but nothing works.

It is because of the $(-1)$ that nothing is poss

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging a little bit, we have the equation $4\times 3^x = 5^y+1$

If there were in fact solutions, then looking at this modulo $4$ we have

$4\times 3^x \equiv 5^y+1\pmod{4}$

However...

> This would imply that $0\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The given equation $\implies 4\times 3^x=5^y+1$

**RHS:-**

> $5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \implies 5^y \equiv 1 \pmod 4\implies 5^y+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

**LHS:-**

> But, $4 \times 3^y \equiv 0 \pmod 4$

Saying simply, **the LHS gives remainder 0 and the RHS gives remainder 2** when divided by 4.

> $\therefore LHS≠RHS$. Hence, there is no such $(x,y)$.